# Azure VM and Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, port, azure-vm

I have an Azure VM running an Ubuntu 18.04 os. On this VM I created an NSG with `Ports 80 and 22` Inbound rule. When trying to install VSCode on the VM, however, the code server starts on `port 8080`.

Then I tunneled port `8080` to `80`, but I simply cannot establish a Connection from the browser to  my VSCode when I try to load `http://<public ip adress>:80`

What am I doing wrong???

I thank you in advance for your help!

[PuTTY Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CdMR.png)

[Run VSCode on Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z22PM.png)

[NSG Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RtIE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is listening only on interface 127.0.0.1 which represents your VM. If you want to listen on any address (including your public IP), let your server listen on 0.0.0.0 instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the problem starting the code server using the --host 0.0.0.0 option